# Appending python dictionary to list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a doc list and a dict dictionary.

```
doc = []
somedict = {}

somedict['facets'] = "blue"
doc.append(somedict)
somedict['facets'] = "green"
doc.append(somedict)
```

Expected output when I give command

```
print doc
```

Expected output:

```
[ {'facets':'blue'} , {'facets':'green'} ]
```

Present output:

```
[{'facets': 'green'}, {'facets': 'green'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right implementation should be like below:

```
doc = []
dict = {}

dict['facets'] = "blue"
doc.append(dict)

dict = {} # Declare a new dict here
dict['facets'] = "green"
doc.append(dict)
```

In your code, the second append for doc add the same one dict object as the first append, which results in doc containing the same dict object twice.

Comment: thnks its satisfactory :)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the *same dictionary* twice. Adding an object to a list does not create a copy, you simply add another reference to the same object.

You could create a copy before changing the key (`somedict = somedict.copy()`) or when appending (`doc.append(somedict.copy())`), but since you have just the one key I'd create a *new* dictionary instead:

```
doc = []

somedict = {'facets': "blue"}
doc.append(somedict)
somedict = {'facets': "green"}
doc.append(dict)`
```

or even

```
doc = [{'facets': "blue"}, {'facets': "green"}]
```